# Can I control the order of keyboard layouts in the system menu?

Tags: macos, input-source

I have a few keyboard layouts or "input sources" as the system calls them. The system also lets you define a keyboard shortcut for "Select next source in Input menu".

[image]

I had muscle memory of how many times to hit that key combo to go between various keyboards. Then after a reboot they are now in different order. Is there a way to set the order so it doesn't change?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: The latest - 10.13.4 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using more than two input sources you'd be better off configuring a specific shortcut for each input source.

Without knowing the exact version of macOS you're running, there are a number of tools you could use to achieve this:

- [IMEShortcuts](http://rockcell.net/#features)
- [MLSwitcher2](https://bluezbox.com/mlswitcher2.html)
- [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)

My suggestion would be to create the same shortcut and use digits (i.e. 1, 2, 3, and 4) to differentiate them.

Comment: Hi Rob, just wondering if you've had a chance to try any of the tools I mentioned? Did you get this sorted in the end?